# Android: Default preference value not being set from XML

Tags: android, default-value, android-preferences

I have a simple Preferences Activity that I populate via XML, defining the values as array resources.

In the MAIN Activity of the application, I get a handle to this via:

```
mSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

In the XML for the only preference I have, which is a display setting, I have the following XML that defines the ListPreference:

```
<ListPreference
        android:title="@string/pref_title_sort"
        android:summary="@string/pref_summary_sort"
        android:key="@string/pref_key_sort"
        android:defaultValue="modified"
        android:entries="@array/sort_order"
        android:entryValues="@array/sort_order_values" />
```

You can see I am trying to set the default value to 'modified', which is a value found in @array/sort_order_values:

```
<string-array name="sort_order_values">
    <item>modified</item>
    <item>created</item>
    <item>name</item>
</string-array>
```

However, when the Preferences Activity is launched, none of the items are selected by default.

I've tried adding the following line to my Activity, but it did not change anything (where pref_main is the XML file that defines the preferences):

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.pref_main, false);
```

Any help appreciated!

Paul

Answer (score 2):

Maybe You have just set a wrong value (without corresponding item in the value array) at the first time you run application. Now Android remembers your first choice. Try to manually uninstall app (Menu >> Settings >> Applications >> Manage Applications >>  >> Uninstall ). This should help.